# Best way to build an activation/password reset link

Tags: security, passwords, token, reset, activation

What’s the best way to build a link containing an activation or password reset token? The URL would be delivered via email and the user would be expected to click on it to either activate their account or reset their password. There are a bunch of threads on this but there doesn’t appear to be a consistent approach, and each approach appears to have advantages and disadvantages from both a security and development perspective:

1. Link includes token as a parameter and email address in the query string

   ```
   http://www.example.com/activations/:token?email=joe@gmail.com
   ```

   With this approach, the token is hashed in the database and the email is used to look up the user. The token is then compared to the hashed version in the database using a library like brycpt. It seems though that including sensitive data, such as an email address in the query string, [exposes some security risks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string).
2. Link only includes token either as parameter or query string.

   ```
   http://www.example.com/activations/:token
   ```

   This would appear to be the ideal solution, but I don’t know how to compare the tokens unless the token stored in the database is unhashed. From a security standpoint, some have argued that the [token in the database doesn't need to be hashed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40310/generating-an-unguessable-token-for-confirmation-e-mails), while others argue the [token should be hashed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86913/should-password-reset-tokens-be-hashed-when-stored-in-a-database). Assuming we keep a hashed token in the database, iterating through each token in the database and comparing with the token in the link seems very time consuming, particularly in apps with lots of users. So perhaps I'm wrong about this, but it seems that using this approach would require that I store the token in the database unhashed.

Anybody have any thoughts on the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no arguments against using method 2 containing only the token.

It is correct that only a hash of the token should be stored in the database (SQL-injection). The problem you see, comes from using BCrypt:

1. Bcrypt includes a **salt**, which prevents searching for the token in the database.
2. Because BCrypt applies **key-stretching** the verification is very slow, so it is impossible to check against every stored hash.

Those two techniques, salting and key-stretching, are mandatory for storing weak passwords, they make brute-forcing unpracticable. Because our token is a very strong "password" (minimum 20 characters 0-9 a-z A-Z) there is no need for these techniques, you can store an unsalted SHA-256 of the token in the database. Such a hash can be searched for directly with SQL.

To show that it is really safe, lets do a simple calculation. A 20 character token would allow for 7E35 combinations. If we can calculate [3 Giga SHA-256 per second](http://thepasswordproject.com/oclhashcat_benchmarking), we would still expect about 3'700'000'000'000'000'000 years to find a match.

Just make sure the token is created from a cryptographically random source.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've been using bcrypt to hash, so it never occurred to me that I could hash without using a salt!